# Azure Transform XML to JSON

Tags: json, xml, azure, azure-logic-apps, dotliquid

I'm trying to transform the following XML into JSON using Azure liquid mapping to find the session ID.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<LogInResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/RLXSOAP19/RLXSOAP19">
<LogInResult>
<ExceptionCode>0</ExceptionCode>
<ExceptionDescription>No error</ExceptionDescription>
</LogInResult>
<SessionID>A VALUE</SessionID>
</LogInResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to use this liquid file to convert the XML to find the sessionID in JSON.

```
{
"Session": "{{content.soap:Envelope.soap:Body.LogInResponse.SessionID}}"
}
```

This just returns no value in the output:

```
{
  "Session": ""
}
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer,

```
{

"Session": "{{content.Envelope.Body.LogInResponse.SessionID}}"

}
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to using a liquid map, you can wrap the xml data in a `json()` workflow function. The statement would look like this:

```
@json(xml(outputs('Mock_example_data')))['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['LogInResponse']['SessionID']
```

This `xml` function above is used because the `outputs` from a *Compose* action named *Mock_example_data* is in string form.